# SelectedItem event fire before LostFocus to update source

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, xaml, triggers

I have piece of code that binds a Collection to the DataGrid, and the selection of the DataGrid will allows detail edit in the TextBoxes.

So basically DataGrid binds to a Collection, TextBoxes binds to the DataGrid.SelectedItem.(properties).

The problem here is when something editted in the TextBoxes  (say add a character in textbox, without losting focus), then select another item in DataGrid (now lost focus).  The DataGrid will update it SelectedItem property, but now the changes that suppose to make on the previous item is gone, the PropertyChanged event was not fire when the lost focus event happens.

I know I could solve it by using `UpdateTriggerSource=PropertyChanged`, but there is quite a lot of event firing around if I using `PropertyChanged`, so I want to see if there is a solution to solve this problem.

And below is my sample code that can reproduce this problem:

Code-Behind:

```
public partial class MainPage : UserControl
{
    Person _SelectedPerson { get; set; }
    public Person SelectedPerson
    {
        get
        {
            return this._SelectedPerson;
        }
        set
        {
            if (this._SelectedPerson == value)
                return;
            this._SelectedPerson = value;
        }
    }

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Person personA = new Person() { FirstName = "Orange", LastName = "Cake" };
        Person personB = new Person() { FirstName = "Apple", LastName = "Pie" };
        ObservableCollection<Person> aPersonCollection = new ObservableCollection<Person>();
        aPersonCollection.Add(personA);
        aPersonCollection.Add(personB);

        MyDataGrid.ItemsSource = aPersonCollection;
        this.DataContext = this;
    }
}

public class Person : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    string _LastName { get; set; }
    public string LastName
    {
        get
        {
            return this._LastName;
        }
        set
        {
            if (this._LastName == value)
                return;
            this._LastName = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged("LastName");
        }
    }

    string _FirstName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName
    {
        get
        {
            return this._FirstName;
        }
        set {
            if (this._FirstName == value)
                return;
            this._FirstName = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged("FirstName");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    void OnPropertyChanged(string property)
    { 
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
    }
```

XAML:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
    <StackPanel>
        <sdk:DataGrid x:Name="MyDataGrid" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPerson, Mode=TwoWay}" />
        <TextBox Text="{Binding SelectedItem.FirstName, ElementName=MyDataGrid, Mode=TwoWay}" />
        <TextBox Text="{Binding SelectedItem.LastName, ElementName=MyDataGrid, Mode=TwoWay}" />
    </StackPanel>            
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add and logic to the leave event of the text box that has been edited.  That should fire prior to the datagrid getting focus.

Comment: It won't work. By default the UpdateTriggerSource event is LostFocous already. Even if you add a piece code for leave event (`LostFocus`) it still fire after SelectedItem event.  Which will replaced your changes on the previous selecteditem.